# New browser window is not opening for 2nd feature file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

When I run the TestRunner class, browser is closing in after first feature and not opening new browser when 2nd feature starts.
Getting following error message

Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:22:35.584Z'
System info: host: 'FIDJ0MXS2Y', ip: '10.76.49.102', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.80, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\sdad\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:16773}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 071afb952f9a259f9df29a9809d3e4b7

```
package context;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScenarioContext
{
    private Map<String, Object> scenarioContext;

    public ScenarioContext(){
        scenarioContext = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setContext(String key, Object value){
        scenarioContext.put(key.toString(), value);
    }

    public Object getContext(String key){
        return scenarioContext.get(key);
    }

    public Boolean isContains(String key){
        return scenarioContext.containsKey(key);
    }
}
```

```
package context;

import managers.PageObjectManager;
import managers.WebDriverManager;

public class TestContext
{
    private WebDriverManager webDriverManager;
    private PageObjectManager pageObjectManager;
    private ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    public TestContext()
    {
        webDriverManager = new WebDriverManager();
        pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager(webDriverManager.getWebDriver());
        scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
    }
    public WebDriverManager getWebDriverManager()
    {
        return webDriverManager;
    }

    public PageObjectManager getPageObjectManager()
    {
        return pageObjectManager;
    }

    public ScenarioContext getScenarioContext(){
        return scenarioContext;
    }
}
```

```
package managers;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import pages.*;

public class PageObjectManager
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    HomePage homePage;
    Page1 page1;
    Page2 page2;

    public PageObjectManager(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public HomePage getHomePage()
    {
        return (homePage == null) ? homePage = new HomePage(driver) : homePage;
    }

    public Page1 getPage1()
    {
        return (page1 == null) ? page1 = new Page1(driver) : page1;
    }

    public Page2 getPage2()
    {
        return (page2 == null) ? page2 = new Page2(driver) : page2;
    }

}
```

```
package managers;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WebDriverManager
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriverManager(){}

    synchronized public static WebDriver getWebDriver()
    {
        if(driver == null)
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\sdad\\Downloads\\Softwares\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        else
        {
            return driver;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package pages;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class HomePage {

    WebDriver driver;
    public HomePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void goToHomePage()
    {
        this.driver.navigate().to("C:\\Users\\sdad\\Downloads\\Projects\\Learning\\WebPages\\page_1.html");
    }

    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        this.driver.close();
//        this.driver.quit();
    }
}
```

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Page1
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(name = "fname_page_1")
    WebElement firstName;

    @FindBy(name = "lname_page_1")
    WebElement lastName;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Page 2']")
    WebElement page2Button;

    public Page1(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void enterFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName.sendKeys(firstName);
    }
    public void enterLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName.sendKeys(lastName);
    }
    public void clickPage2Button(){
        page2Button.click();
    }
}
```

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Page2
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(name = "fname_page_2")
    WebElement firstName;

    @FindBy(name = "lname_page_2")
    WebElement lastName;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Page 3']")
    WebElement page3Button;

    public Page2(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void enterFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName.sendKeys(firstName);
    }
    public void enterLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName.sendKeys(lastName);
    }
    public void clickPage3Button()
    {
        page3Button.click();
    }
}
```

```
Feature: Page 1 Feature

  Scenario: Page 1 - Scenario - 1
    Given I will in home page

  Scenario: Page 1 - Scenario - 2
    Then I will enter Dada in page 1 first name
    And I will enter peer in page 1 last name
    And I will click page 2 button
    And I will close the browser
```

```
Feature: Page 2 Feature

  Scenario: Page 2 - Scenario - 1
    Given I will in home page

  Scenario: Page 2 - Scenario - 2
    And I will click page 2 button
    Then I will enter Dada in page 2 first name
    And I will enter peer in page 2 last name
    And I will click page 3 button
    And I will close the browser
```

```
package stepDefinitions;

import context.TestContext;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import pages.HomePage;

public class HomePageStep {

    TestContext testContext;
    HomePage homePage;

    public HomePageStep(TestContext testContext)
    {
        this.testContext = testContext;
        homePage = testContext.getPageObjectManager().getHomePage();
    }

    @And("^I will in home page$")
    public void goToHomePage()
    {
        homePage.goToHomePage();
    }

    @And("^I will close the browser$")
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        homePage.closeBrowser();
    }

}
```

```
package stepDefinitions;

import context.TestContext;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import pages.Page1;

public class Page1Step {
    TestContext testContext;
    Page1 page1;

    public  Page1Step(TestContext testContext)
    {
        this.testContext = testContext;
        page1 = testContext.getPageObjectManager().getPage1();
    }

    @And("^I will enter ([^\"]*) in page 1 first name$")
    public void enterFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        page1.enterFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @And("^I will enter ([^\"]*) in page 1 last name$")
    public void enterLastName(String lastName)
    {
        page1.enterLastName(lastName);
    }

    @And("^I will click page 2 button$")
    public void clickPage2Button() throws InterruptedException {
        page1.clickPage2Button();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

```
package stepDefinitions;

import context.TestContext;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import pages.Page2;

public class Page2Step {
    TestContext testContext;
    Page2 page2;

    public  Page2Step(TestContext testContext)
    {
        this.testContext = testContext;
        page2 = testContext.getPageObjectManager().getPage2();
    }

    @And("^I will enter ([^\"]*) in page 2 first name$")
    public void enterFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        page2.enterFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @And("^I will enter ([^\"]*) in page 2 last name$")
    public void enterLastName(String lastName)
    {
        page2.enterLastName(lastName);
    }

    @And("^I will click page 3 button$")
    public void clickPage3Button() throws InterruptedException {
        page2.clickPage3Button();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: This is where using [dependency injection](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) can help. This would allow you to create a new insurance of web driver for each scenario and pass it to all of your step definition classes without having to rely on static state. As you are finding out, static state is not your friend when using Selenium and cucumber.